# Check various CoreData objects

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

I think the easiest way to do this would be to fetch all the objects of the desired entity and then check for the attribute I need. My question is: How to I fetch the data and store it in an `NSArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is probably to use NSPredicate and an NSFetchrequest, here's an example that involves checking a relationship, and checking an attribute, then returning the results as an array.

```
-(NSArray *)pointsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"TourPoint" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tour == %@ && section == %i", theTour, section];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *rowSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"row" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowSort, nil]];
return [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

}